# Advantages of Using ArrayList as Datasource Instead of DataTables

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

What is the advantage of using arraylist as datasource  instead of data tables in vb.net?

In my reference code, data from datatable stored to an arraylist and used as data source for a form control. What is the advantage of copying data from table to arraylist.

Comment: Use a strongly typed `List(Of T)` instead of `ArrayList` nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a WinForm app? I'm assuming so since you said "form control".

In general, in a WinForms app using bound controls, it will be best to keep your data in a dataset/datatable. Most classic bound controls won't work as well with newer methods based on LINQ. So, in this bound control scenario, there is no real advantage in most cases to copying data from a DataTable to another object type. In fact, all the copying around might cause your app to run slower, introduce unexpected bugs and unnecessarily complicate some operations.

Outside of bound controls in WinForms, using a strongly typed IEnumerable based class, such as List, makes more sense in most cases. This would also apply if you're doing web based applications or WPF applications.